# Network 'device is strictly unmanaged', trying to make static IP work

Tags: networking, server, 22.04, network-manager, static-ip

I have a Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS machine here that needs to be set with static IP address.

I followed [the Linuxize tutorial for employing `netplan`](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-configure-static-ip-address-on-ubuntu-20-04/), plus [the StackExchange update on the new syntax](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/681220/netplan-generate-gateway4-has-been-deprecated-use-default-routes-instead) to set `/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml` as follows:

```
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: networkd
    ethernets:
        enp2s0f0:
            dhcp4: no
            addresses:
                - 172.16.86.3/24
            routes:
                - to: default
                    via: 172.16.86.2
            nameservers:
                addresses: [200.131.157.4, 8.8.8.8]
```

The file `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` is like this:

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
 
[ifupdown]
managed=true
 
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

I've tried `nmcli dev set enp2s0f0 managed yes`

But `nmcli device status` still shows:

```
DEVICE      TYPE        STATE       CONNECTION
enp2s0f0    ethernet    unmanaged   --
enp2s0f1    ethernet    unmanaged   --
enp2s0f2    ethernet    unmanaged   --
enp2s0f3    ethernet    unmanaged   --
lo          loopback    unmanaged   --
```

And `nmtui` is of no help:

```
[Activate a connection]
[Ethernet connection 1]
 
Could not activate connection:
Connection 'Ethernet Connection
1' is not available on device
enp2s0f0 because device is
strictly unmanaged.
[OK]
```

So, what should I do to make device manageable? Is this what I need in order to make the static IP work, or I am acting on wrong assumptions?

**Please add output of `ip a`.**

[Here it is](https://pastebin.com/955BNuee):

```
1: lo:  mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever     
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp2s0f0:  mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:25:90:5a:[...] brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 127.16.86.3/24 brd 172.16.86.255 scope global enp2s0f0
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever     
    inet6 fe80::255:90ff:fe5a:fe/64 scope link
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever 
3: enp2s0f1:  mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:25:90:5a:[...] brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: enp2s0f2:  mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000 
    link/ether 00:25:90:5a:[...] brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: enp2s0f3:  mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:25:90:5a:[...] brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Comment: It is unclear why you need NM at all. Please add output of `ip a`. And is it a desktop or a server? You need to choose one way to setup your interface, not both.

Comment: @Pilot6 It is a server. I have added `ip a` output to the question description. NetworkManager was used because that's what shows up on Google when searching for a way to set up static IP addresses, most of the time.

Comment: So you've setup a static IP. What is the problem? It shouldn't be manageable on nmcli.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your device is managed by `networkd`.

You've successfully setup a static IP as it is shown by `ip a`.

It shouldn't be managable by NetworkManager, because it is not used.

Comment: I have `renderer: networkd` because [the Linuxize tutorial said to put this in there](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-configure-static-ip-address-on-ubuntu-20-04/). But it also says this line is not required. How about just deleting it and letting the OS figure out what to do?

Comment: Correct: the static IP works, and the "strictly unmanaged" WORK AS INTENDED, as you said. I tested today.